# serverless with nodejs and lambda - functions not being called on lambda but does getting called localy

Tags: node.js, lambda, serverless

i try to build a small lambda function to communicate with amazon MWS

my index.js route requests to amazon/fba.js

```
app.post('/*', function(req, response){
  r = req.path.split('/');
  console.log(`./${r[1]}/${r[2]}.js`)
  require(`./${r[1]}/${r[2]}.js`)(req.body,req);
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With," +" Content-Type, Accept");
  response.send(req.body);    // echo the result back

});
```

than, on fba.js i require amazon-mws

```
var amazonMws = require('amazon-mws')('MYKEY','MYSECRET');


module.exports = function(initValue) {
  var fba_obj = {
    'Version': '2010-10-01',
    'Action': 'CreateFulfillmentOrder',
    'SellerId': 'XXXXXX',
    'MarketplaceId': 'YYYYY',
    'MWSAuthToken': 'amzn.mws.XXXXX',
    'SellerFulfillmentOrderId': initValue.order,
    'ShippingSpeedCategory': 'Standard',
    'DisplayableOrderId': initValue.DisplayableOrderId,
    'DisplayableOrderDateTime': initValue.DisplayableOrderDateTime,
    'DisplayableOrderComment': initValue.DisplayableOrderComment,
    'DestinationAddress.Name': initValue.Customer.name,
    'DestinationAddress.Line1': initValue.Customer.address1,
    'DestinationAddress.Line2': initValue.Customer.address2,
    'DestinationAddress.City': initValue.Customer.city,
    'DestinationAddress.StateOrProvinceCode': initValue.Customer.state,
    'DestinationAddress.PostalCode': initValue.Customer.postal,
    'DestinationAddress.CountryCode': initValue.Customer.country,
    'DestinationAddress.DistrictOrCounty': '',
    'DestinationAddress.PhoneNumber': initValue.Customer.phone
  }

  initValue.products.forEach((item, i) => {
    z = i+1;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.DisplayableComment'] = item.comment;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.GiftMessage'] = item.giftMessage;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.PerUnitDeclaredValue.Value'] = item.unitPrice;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.PerUnitDeclaredValue.CurrencyCode'] = item.currency;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.FulfillmentNetworkSKU'] = item.fnsku;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.Quantity'] = item.quantity;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.SellerFulfillmentOrderItemId'] = item.ssku;
    fba_obj['Items.member.'+z+'.SellerSKU'] = item.ssku;
  });

  console.log('call fba with data',fba_obj);
  amazonMws.fulfillmentOutboundShipment.create(fba_obj, function (error, response) {
    console.log('error',error);
    console.log('fba response',response);
      if (error) {
          console.log('error ', error);
          return;
      }
      console.log('reached end of');
  });
}
```

when i run the sls deploy offline the function `amazonMws.fulfillmentOutboundShipment.create` runs correctly and order is being created on the amazon merchant center. when i run the app on lambda, the same function does not seem to execute at all.  i tried logs and seems that app stop (without any error) before the call the merchant.

i tried debuging the initValue variable and verified i'm using the same object on both local and lambda

Comment: can u just do `return amazonMws.fulfillmentOutboundShipment.create(..)` and check if that works?

Comment: i'm going to give it a try

Comment: @AritraChakraborty that did not seems to work ask well